# How to access css style of div in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

I want to access the div in c# page which has css styling. I want that when the div is empty means image is not set in it.It shows 0 value but if div has filled with image it shows the value of 3.How can I get this functionality or how can I access the div in c# in right way?Any help will be appreciated.Thank you

```js
function tiger() {
document.getElementById("logo").style = "background-image:url(logoimages/tiger.png)"}
```

```css
 #logo {
width: 85px;
height:150px;
background-image: url('');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
.btn_back{
background-color:transparent;
border:1px solid black;
margin-top:15px;
margin-left:15px;
}
.btn_back:focus{
outline:none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn_back" onclick="tiger()"><img src="logoimages/tiger.png"  style="height:50px;width:50px"/></button>
<div id="logo" runat="server"></div>
```

Comment: Your C# code runs **on the server**, before the page is sent to the browser. Then, later, the JavaScript in the page is run **on the browser**. To send information back to the server, you need to make a request to the server (ajax, send a form, etc.).

Comment: I make request through ajax but it does not work

Comment: T.J.Crowder I use it but not working. If anyone else have some solution then help me please

Comment: you can just use your div in your codebehind as your div is running at server. for example `logo.Attributes["style"] = "background-color: red";`